# ls aliases in .bash_aliases interfering with egrep output

Tags: linux, aliases

I have the following lines in my .bash_aliases file:

```
# Prettify and streamline listings
alias ls='ls --color'
alias ll='ls -l'
alias la='ls -a'
alias lla='ls -al'
alias lF='ls -F'
alias laF='ls -laF'
alias llF='ls -lF'
alias llaF='ls -alF'
```

The aliases work fine but I run into trouble when piping to egrep to look for invisible files. For example, if I want to list all the invisible files in the directory, and I type `la | egrep '^\.'` I get no output. Even if I skip the alias and type `ls -a | egrep '^\.'` I still get no output. If I leave out the caret, it works, but of course in that case `egrep` lists all files with a period in the filename, not just those that begin with a period.

However, if I rename the .bash_aliases file and log in again, so that these aliases are not active, then `ls -a | egrep '^\.'` works just fine to list the invisible files. Very odd.

I am trying to figure out why this is happening and I'm drawing a blank. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following command and you will see some the reason:

```
ls --color | cat -v
```

You should use the alias `ls='ls --color=auto'` instead of `ls='ls --color'`.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for your help. That fixed it, and I learned something. You rock, nosid.